# Visual Studio 2008 Painfully Slow Under SVN

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have recently been through the pain of converting an legacy WebSite project to a (C#)Web Application Project. During this time I also migrated the code from VSS control to Subversion on a dev server.

When debugging the application under VS2008 the project can literally take 4/5 minutes to completely load up. The majority of this time the Output Window states that it is loading symbols from Temp ASP.NET directory.

Figuring this may be an issue that it is under SVN control, I exported the project and began debugging without source control and this resolved the issue.

Can anyone suggest why this could be happening, ie. why under source control is it taking such a long time to debug?

Comment: Why would loading symbols have anything to do with source control?

Comment: If you are **not** using a Visual Studio plug-in (AnkhSvn?), then SVN is (as far as Visual Studio is concerned), a bunch of .svn sub-folders which are not included in your project in any way, doing absolutely nothing.

So your real question should be "Why is ASP.Net debugging so painfully slow?"

Answer (score 2):

Symbol loading shouldn't have anything to do with .svn. If moving your project solved the problem, I'd guess it's something to do with the difference between your actual copy and the exported one. Particularly, I'd say it would be to do with a file unlikely to be committed, like a ".user" file. The ".user" file probably has a lot of extra junk that VS is trying to load, and moving it means they got reset.

Check for any files missing (after a clean export...they'll have been re-created after you open the solution 1x) and you'll probably find the culprit.

Comment: Excellent advice I will do that now and check if there are any file differences.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) client

The more plugins (Resharper etc) you have for VS the slower things tend to get.

Comment: I am using TortoiseSVN. As I said though the problem goes away when source is not under source control. So has nothing to do with plugins etc. The issue is particular to having source under source control.

Comment: Is VSS perhaps still trying to connect to the files?